# Disable default scope for associations in module / Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations, activesupport-concern

I have a concern where I want to have unscoped association, But could not able to get it. In one of my instance method , I have a logic like that:
Assume I want to use only one parent (`belongs_to`)

```
parent_class_name = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).last

parent = nil
if parent_class_name.present?
   parent_class_const = parent_class_name.to_s.camelize.constantize

    parent_class_const.send(:unscoped) do
      parent = self.send(parent_class_name)
    end
end
```

The parent association has always the default scope, which should not be case. Similarly I have logic for `has_many` association, but that also does not work.

Looking forward for help.

P.S I don't want to use any gem

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the class constant directly:

```
parent_class = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).last.klass
```

Then you can call `unscoped` on the class directly:

```
parent_class.unscoped do 
  # do the unscoped stuff here
end
```

Comment: undefined method `klass' for :list:Symbol